# Focusing on input changes the width

Tags: html, css

As mentioned in the title, the width changes slightly when focusing on the input element.

[image]

This is a problem that occurs in IE11 and Firefox 83.0.
(It does not occur in chrome and safari.)

If you know the cause, please let me know.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help you.

Comment: Older versions of browsers some time cause problem so always keep your browsers updated and if possible show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because focusing creates a border, as you can see in the following example:

```css
.focus:focus {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input class="focus" />
```

You can fix this by using adding an empty border first:

```css
.focus {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.focus:focus {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input class="focus" />
```